# writing pandas series into tab separated file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series y which I generated by group by and looks like

```
Item   Attribute  Feature
aaaa   x1         f1,f2
       x2         f3,f4
bbbb   x3         f5
       x4         f6
```

I want to generate a tab delimted output that looks exactly as above. When I try

```
y.to_csv('out',sep = "\t")
```

I get

```
Item   Attribute   Feature
aaaa   x1         f1,f2
aaaa   x2         f3,f4
bbbb   x3         f5
bbbb   x4         f6
```

I want to avoid repetition of elements in the "Item" column. Can you help

Comment: You should realize that if you save that df output. You may not be able to easily bring that df back into pandas namespace. AFAIK..

Comment: I don't intend to bring that object back into pandas, it is much easier reading the output in the series form

Answer (score 1):

The text you want isn't `csv`.

Assume `df` is your dataframe or series:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.__repr__())
```

---

#### `to_txt` function

```
import pandas as pd

def to_txt(df, fn=None):
    x, c, r = ['expand_frame_repr', 'max_columns', 'max_rows']
    current_max_col = pd.get_option(c)
    current_max_row = pd.get_option(r)
    current_xpd_frm = pd.get_option(x)

    pd.set_option(x, False)
    pd.set_option(c, df.shape[1])
    pd.set_option(r, df.shape[0])

    if fn is not None:
        with open(fn, 'w') as f:
            f.write(df.__repr__())
    else:
        return df.__repr__()

    pd.set_option(x, current_xpd_frm)
    pd.set_option(c, current_max_col)
    pd.set_option(r, current_max_row)
```

#### Demonstration

```
to_text(df, 'test_file.txt')
```

Comment: This works but if the number of Items is very large, it does not print all rows in the output, prints ... in the middle

Comment: @Ssank I've updated the post with a function to do it.